# Как исправить ошибку подключения к сети

Tags: android, kotlin, сеть

Написал небольшое приложение Android, которое подключается к сети чтобы считывать информацию из файла json, который находится в моем репозитории в github. На многих устройствах работает отлично, но есть также достаточно устройств (например Redmi 10, Samsung A33), которые никак не хотят подключаться к сети.

Смотрел через логгер, выдает это:

```
failed to connect to jdwp control socket: Connection refused
```

Кто-нибудь встречался с подобным? Не знаете, как решить?

Код:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDataCaller() = DataCaller()

@Provides
fun provideOkHttp(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        // disable network cache
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient) : Retrofit {
    val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideLinksApi(retrofit: Retrofit): LinksApi = retrofit.create(LinksApi::class.java)
```

Добавляю Манифест по просьбе:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:requestRawExternalStorageAccess="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.screens.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove"/>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

Comment: +манифест и network config

Comment: Можно пожалуйста подробнее?

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно, это поможет. Попробуйте добавить в манифест в раздел application следующую строку: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".

Comment: +добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @Style-7 добавил манифест. NetworkModule.kt и так есть

Comment: нет, вы не добавили network-security-config

Comment: @Style-7 Значит у меня его нет. Подскажите куда добавить и как?

Comment: это все ищется на 123 :), дело не в телефонах а версиях Андроид которые на них стоят.

Comment: @Style-7 добавил ответ, проверьте пожалуйста)))

Answer (score 0):

По советам @Style-7 добавил в манифест в раздел application:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Также создал файл res/xml/network_security_config.xml с таким содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Достаточно ли это? Чтобы проверить работоспособность, нужно обращаться к пользователям, у которых выявилась такая проблема. Поэтому хочется всё уточнить и перепроверить.

Правильное ли у меня содержимое в файле network_security_config? Где то читал, что нужно указывать домены и поэтому есть сомнения.

Comment: ну конечно нужно свой домен указывать